# No me aparecem las recomendaciones de XML

Tags: android-studio, xml, kotlin

Al definir un `TextView`, me deberían de aparecer las recomendaciones como  `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, pero lo único que me aparece es esto que muestro en la imagen:

[image: imagen del error]

Answer (score 0):

Si no se están mostrando las sugerencias, seguramente tienes la opción "Power Save Mode" activada.

En la esquina inferior derecha de Android Studio puedes acceder a esta opción, debes deshabilitarla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]